# Pyside2: QSplitter replaceWidget not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyside2, qsplitter

I have a `QSplitter` with two widgets in it and want to replace one of them:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, 
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QSplitter, QTextEdit, QLabel)


class Example(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        splitter = QSplitter()
        splitter.insertWidget(0, QLabel('test'))
        splitter.insertWidget(1, QTextEdit())

        print(splitter.count())  # prints 2
        splitter.replaceWidget(1, QLabel('something else'))
        print(splitter.count())  # prints 1

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(splitter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()

    main = Example()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My understanding of `replaceWidget` is that it will replace an existing widget on index X in the splitter by the provided widget. In the above example on index 0 there's a `QLabel('test')` and on index 1 `QTextEdit()`.

After trying to replace the widget on index 1, I would expect it to be `QLabel('something else')`. But it seems that the widget on index 1 just gets deleted from looking at the output of the `count()` before and after the replace operation.

Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: "it seems that the widget on index 1 just gets deleted looking at the output of the count()" What do you mean? If the previous widget gets replaced, the count will be the same after that as it was before.

Comment: @musicamante sorry I've missed to share the actual output; the output I've received was `2` before and `1` after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug in PySide2. The count should be 2 after `replaceWidget()` is called, but it's 1.

According to the [docs for replaceWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#replaceWidget), the splitter should take ownership of the new widget and reparent it. But PySide seems to lose track of it somehow - so presumably it just gets garbage-collected. The same code run in PyQt5 works as expected, although the inserted widget still won't show up (because [reparenting will always make a widget invisble](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent)). The way to work around these issues is to make sure the widget has a parent before inserting it in the splitter, and then call `show()` on it afterwards:

```
    label = QLabel('something else', self)

    print(splitter.count())
    splitter.replaceWidget(1, label)
    print(splitter.count())

    label.show()
```

This works correctly for me in both PySide2 (5.15.2) and PyQt5 (5.15.2).